# How to get and set a value to and from an asp HiddenField

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, boolean, hiddenfield

I want to add a Boolean value to a `HiddenField` ASP.NET controller so that the value can be retained after postback. Here is my code:

```
Public Property IsAddingNewCause() As Boolean
    Get 
        Return IsAddingNewCauseField.value
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        IsAddingNewCauseField.value = value          
       '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^this is where I want to set the HiddenField's value!
    End Set
End Property
```

**ASP.NET Markup**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstNewCause" runat="server" DataSource="..." >
    <EditItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="IsAddingNewCauseField" runat="server" Value="" />
```

[...]

**EDIT**

The problem is that the control's ID is not being found:
`Error  311 Name 'IsAddingNewCauseField' is not declared.`

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: So you're saying in the setter of your property, the hiddenfield value isn't being set?  How do you know?

Comment: What is the containing control?

Comment: please view the edit for the error message

Comment: the containing control is a <asp:ListView>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckons you need to search the listviews controls for it. The control doesn't get a designer entry and only exists when created dynamically.  I might be wrong as I'm on my phone and can't check.

Edit included code, its going to be along these lines.

```
Protected Sub lstNewCause_ItemUpdated(sender As Object, e As ListViewUpdatedEventArgs)

    Dim l As ListView = DirectCast(sender, ListView)

    Dim item As ListViewItem = lstNewCause.Items(l.SelectedIndex)

    Dim IsAddingNewCauseField As HiddenField = DirectCast(item.FindControl("IsAddingNewCauseField"), HiddenField)

    '...do your stuff


End Sub
```

Comment: that was it! I took the hiddenField out of the listview and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Please when you have time, specify how you would have done it to find the `HiddenField` from inside the `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

HiddenField value property type is String. You must convert IsAddingNewCauseField.Value to Boolean in the get and call value.ToString() in the set accessor.